# Where are my points?

Tags: support, reputation, migration

I could have sworn that I had over 1,900 reputation points this morning. After the migration, I have considerably fewer. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were changes to the reputation system which are outlined here:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/

We recalculated all reputation for everyone as a result of the site migration.